# Why does responsive table is not working as expected?

Tags: html, css, html-table, responsive, css-tables

I'm trying to make a table responsive, but it's not working as I expect.

```
<figure class="i_table"><table><tbody><tr><td>Title-1</td><td>Title-2</td></tr><tr><td>A</td><td>B</td></tr><tr><td>Title-3</td><td>Title-4</td></tr><tr><td>C</td><td>D</td></tr></tbody></table></figure>
```

CSS

```
    .i_table table {   width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.i_table tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: #eee;
}
.i_table th {
  background: #333;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.i_table td,
th {
  padding: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: left;
}
@media all and (max-width:500px) {

  .i_table table,
  thead,
  tbody,
  th,
  td,
  tr {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Normal Table is ..
[image: Normal Table is]

What is showing
[image: What is showing]

What I'm expecting
[image: What I'm expecting]

I tried here https://jsfiddle.net/7gy9zwox/ but not able to do that

Answer (score 2):

It is not working as you intend because the title cells are siblings that when forced to display as full-width cells display next to each other.

To keep your title and content cells together, they need to be somehow grouped together so that they stay together. I have done this by putting the title and content cells in `span` elements that are styled to appear and behave like your table cells.

```css
.i_table table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.i_table td > span:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: #eee;
}

.i_table th {
  background: #333;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

td > span {
  padding: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: left;
}

@media all and (max-width:500px) {

  .i_table table,
  thead,
  tbody,
  th,
  td,
  tr {
    display: block;
  }
}

td > span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<figure class="i_table">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span>Title-1</span>
                    <span>A</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span>Title-2</span>
                    <span>B</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span>Title-3</span>
                    <span>C</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span>Title-4</span>
                    <span>D</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</figure>
```